# Android 13 - Access my own file like firmware, data logs WITHOUT MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: android, file-permissions

My app was rejected by google because I used MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, my existing app use both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE target on Android 10 and below, however I need to upgrade to API33 or Android 13 before August this year to meet google's policy.

tested on Android 13, without both READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (android 13 don't use anyway), I can still use new File method to create my own file structure, what's it mean ? I still have write permission ?

```
File sdDirectory = new File(strPath);
boolSDWrite = sdDirectory.mkdirs();
```

```
ROOT \
   COMPANYNAME \ 
    APPNAME\
      data
      update
```

my app used to created both folders named "data" and "update" to store our app owned log files (read write), and firmware file (read)
but on Android 13 without All files access permission (MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) when my app try to create file inside data directory will crash (please see logcat)

```
ROOT \
   COMPANYNAME \ 
    APPNAME\
      data
      update
```

## Logcat

```
Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 13582

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
java.io.FileOutputStream.write(byte[])' on a null object reference
    at com.spt.iofiles.ownappFileCtrl.doWriteEnterToFile(ownappFileCtrl.java:75)
    at com.spt.iofiles.ownappFileCtrl.doWriteIntToFile(ownappFileCtrl.java:180)
    at com.spt.iofiles.ownappFileCtrl.doWriteIntToFileInLine(ownappFileCtrl.java:209)
    at com.xxx.xxx.app.logctrl.ownappLogFileDataSaveThread.doNewLogFile(ownappLogFileDataSaveThread.java:43)
    at com.xxx.xxx.app.logctrl.ownappLogFileDataSaveThread.run(ownappLogFileDataSaveThread.java:172)
```

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: Refer to [Access app-specific files](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/app-specific). You should use `getFilesDir()`, `getExternalFilesDir()`, `getCacheDir()` or `getExternalCacheDir()` for files that only meaningful to your app. As long as you are using these directories, you can freely read and write without needing any permission.